# Cannot upload image to server ( Xamarin Studio Android)

Tags: php, android, xamarin.android, image-uploading

I try to upload an image to server from android smartphone. When I pressed "upload". An image file is created in server but the file's size is 0 KB.

I use Xamarin Studio. Here is what I have done

Client side

```
System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("http://mydomain/datalogger/upload.php", "POST",image_path);
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
```

My **"image_path"** is *"/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/CameraAppDemo/myPhoto_b4f4ec44-fd81-4044-937e-4d35b8823973.jpg";* 

server side(PHP)

```
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
$file = fopen('image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo 'Complete!!'
```

Why I get 0 Kb of image size??. How can I upload image from my smartphone to server??

Comment: Can You lookup what are Your getting in php script? Specifically: What are You getting in $_REQUEST['image']? Did You tried to use $_FILES variable which is designed to handle post upload data?

Comment: On second tought: Why is Your script returning Content-Type: bitmap and printing string output with echo? I've checked valid content types and theres nothing like: bitmap, more like there should be image/bmp. See more types here: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html